# Django error OperationalError, migrations doesnt helped

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

In my localhost I am getting Django OperationalError and in all stackoverflow questions everybody is talking about `python manage.py makemigrations <appname>` and `python manage.py migrate`, but I did the migrations 5 times and I am getting still the same error. Here are my models, views, template and urls file codes. Also I tried to remove `null=True` and `blank=True` arguments from TextField

Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'f/ask/ask.css' %}">
      <title>BareTalk</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="wrapper"> 
       <form method="POST">
           {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
    
            <!-- TODO: input submit Reg() function javascript -->
            <input name="final" id="final" type="submit" value="Ask">
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
   <script src="{% static 'f/ask/ask.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

`views.py`(function-based-views)

```
def Answer(request, pk):
    form = AnswerForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('f'))
    
    content = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'f/answer.html/', content)
```

`models.py`

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    author   = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content  = models.TextField('Body', null=True, blank=True, default='Answer')
    date     = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Answers'
        verbose_name        = 'Answer'
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path('', QuestionListView.as_view(), name='f'),
    path('', index, name='f'),
    path('<hex:pk>/update/', QuestionUpdateView.as_view(), name='question-update'),
    path('<hex:pk>/delete/', QuestionDeleteView.as_view(), name='question-delete'),
    path('new/', QuestionCreateView.as_view(), name='question-create'),
    path('<hex:pk>/', QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='current'),
    path('<hex:pk>/answer', Answer, name='answer')
]
```

and the Django traceback form cmd(terminal)

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table f_answer has no column named author_id
    [03/Sep/2020 10:53:29] "POST /f/1/answer HTTP/1.1" 500 141941
```

Comment: Did you Clear all the migrations?

Comment: No did not that